# Передача значения переменной из activity в fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity, android-viewpager

У меня есть `BusActivity`, в которой я уже знаю значение переменной `position`. У нее есть дочерний фрагмент `BusStopFragment`, который я создаю в методе `SetupViewPager()`. Вопрос состоит в том, как мне передать значение этой переменной `position` в метод `setInitialData()` этого фрагмента?

Код `BusActivity`:

```
public class BusActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bus);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int position;
    int DefaultValue = 0;
    position = intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_POS", DefaultValue);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == android.R.id.home){
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new BusStopFragment(), "BusStop");
    adapter.addFragment(new TableFragment(), "Table");
    adapter.addFragment(new MapFragment(), "Map");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(adapter.getCount());
}
}
```

Код `BusStopFragment`:

```
public class BusStopFragment extends Fragment {

private List<Station> stations = new ArrayList();

ListView stationsList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setInitialData();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.busstopfragment, container, false);
    stationsList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.stationsList);
    Activity activity = new Activity();
    StationAdapter stationAdapter = new StationAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, stations);
    stationsList.setAdapter(stationAdapter);
    return view;
}

private void setInitialData(){
    stations.add(new Station("01", "10 grn", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background));
    stations.add(new Station("02", "15 grn", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background));
    stations.add(new Station("03", "20 grn", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте интерфейс ICallbacks

```
public interface ICallbacks {
    int getPosition();
}
```

Затем замените код в активности (имплементируйте этот интерфейс, реализуйте метод getPosition(), вынесите переменную position на уровень класса)

```
public class BusActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ICallbacks {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    private int position;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bus);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int DefaultValue = 0;
        position = intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_POS", DefaultValue);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == android.R.id.home){
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new BusStopFragment(), "BusStop");
        adapter.addFragment(new TableFragment(), "Table");
        adapter.addFragment(new MapFragment(), "Map");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(adapter.getCount());
    }

    @Override
    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Затем измените код во фрагменте (создайте переменные ICallbacks ICallbacks, int position и переопределите метод onAttach)

```
public class BusStopFragment extends Fragment {
    private List<Station> stations = new ArrayList();
    ListView stationsList;

    private ICallbacks ICallbacks;
    private int position;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setInitialData();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.busstopfragment, container, false);
        stationsList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.stationsList);
        Activity activity = new Activity();
        StationAdapter stationAdapter = new StationAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, stations);
        stationsList.setAdapter(stationAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    private void setInitialData(){
        stations.add(new Station("01", "10 grn", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background));
        stations.add(new Station("02", "15 grn", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background));
        stations.add(new Station("03", "20 grn", R.drawable.ic_launcher_background));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (!(context instanceof ICallbacks)) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement fragment's ICallbacks.");
        }
        ICallbacks = (ICallbacks) context;
        position = ICallbacks.getPosition();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте интерфейс, который будет реализован вашим активити.

```
public interface Busable{
   int getPosition();
```

Добавьте наследование и реализуйте метод getPosition()

```
public class BusActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Busable{
   public int getPosition(){
   return position; // position - перенесите на уровень класса
   }

}
```

Во фрагмент добавьте переменную

```
Busable mainActivity;
```

Переопределите метод onAttach(Activity activity)

```
onAttach(Activity activity){
  mainActivity = (Busable) activity;
```

И получите значение своей переменной

```
mainActivity.getPosition()
```

Comment: а где именно здесь передается значение переменной `position`?

Comment: я не могу перенести `position` на уровень класса, так как я получаю его в методом `intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_POS", 0)` и когда я его выношу, он не видит метод `getIntExtra` пишет(cannot resolve symbol getIntExtra)

Comment: Ну вам же не надо его на уровне класса инициализировать. Вынесите переменную, а инициализируйте в onCreate(), как сейчас. Я просто не могу понять в чем проблема.